# How to prepare my own dataset to NLTK ConditionalFreqDist function?

Tags: python, nltk

NLTK contains the "brown" dataset that contains all the data on the different genres...

```
cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(
    (genre, word)
    for genre in brown.categories()
    for word in brown.words(categories=genre))

genres = ['news', 'religion', 'hobbies', 'science_fiction', 'romance', 'humor']
modals = ['can', 'could', 'may', 'might', 'must', 'will']
cfd.tabulate(conditions=genres, samples=modals)
```

The issue is, brown happens to be a dataset built into nltk with a convenient categories method, but I have no idea how the input data is structured.

If I have my own data I would like to take advantage of the COnditionalFreqDist function, say 50 documents, each with its own "genre/category" how would I be able to format such data in a way that is usable by the function? Should it be in a csv or separate csvs for each genre with each row containing a single document? How to format for input? An example of a small dataset would be great.

If this could be done with perhaps a database connection, instead of flat file, that would be a plus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you head over to the directory where the nltk data is installed, you should be able to look at the files directly. My nltk_data directory is in /home/$user.

The files will be plain-text in a directory structure something like this:

```
./nltk_data/corpora/brown/
```

A sample of the brown files is tokenized text that looks like this:

```
``/`` These/dts actions/nns should/md serve/vb to/to protect/vb in/in fact/nn and/cc in/in effect/nn the/at court's/nn$ wards/nns from/in undue/jj costs/nns and/cc its/pp$ appointed/vbn and/cc elected/vbn servants/nns from/in unmeritorious/jj criticisms/nns ''/'' ,/, the/at jury/nn said/vbd ./.


Regarding/in Atlanta's/np$ new/jj multi-million-dollar/jj airport/nn ,/, the/at jury/nn recommended/vbd ``/`` that/cs when/wrb the/at new/jj management/nn takes/vbz charge/nn Jan./np 1/cd the/at airport/nn be/be operated/vbn in/in a/at manner/nn that/wps will/md eliminate/vb political/jj influences/nns ''/'' ./.
```

For the categories, I think there are two relevant files:

```
categories.pickle
cat.txt
```

The latter is a simple list of each file-name with its category listed alongside. The pickle dump is a set of tuples with the same information (probably created from the .txt file?):

```
('ce21', ['hobbies']), ('ce28', ['hobbies']), ('ce29', ['hobbies'])]
```

You probably just need to create the pickle dump of your categories with the names of your texts, and plop that file in the same directory where you'll be reading your files. (I have not done this myself, so apologies if I am missing something, but it seems in accordance with how nltk is organized.)

Anyway, you can see all of the files and how they're organized simply by finding your nltk_data directory.